# How to map an Array of JSON (of Postgres) into GORM objects and how to process them?

Tags: postgresql, go, jsonb, go-gorm

I am mapping a Postgres table into Golang's GORM Framework. 
How to map the following column type in Postgres?

```
doc json[] DEFAULT ARRAY[]::json[]
```

And how do I modify it with GORM?

Comment: Why `json[]` to begin with? A simple `json` (or better `jsonb`) that contains a JSON array would be way easier to handle I would think

Comment: Depends on what type in Go you want to use to read / write the column from / to.

Comment: @mkopriva what do you mean? Could you show me an example?

Comment: @user6595600 I can't show you an example, or provide more detailed suggestions, without knowing what Go type you're trying to store in the json[] column. i.e. show the Go code you're trying to use and point out the field that corresponds to the column.